# Is it possible to write custom Yaml Deserializer in Jackson?

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

How to write custom Yaml Deserializer using Jackson ?
I can write the JSON Deserializer like below:

```
public class CustomDeserializer  extends JsonDeserializer<SortedMap<String, Object>> {}
```

is there any way to write Yaml Deserializer in same way ?